# Most adequate logic system to formally prove Euler's identity (and what would the proof look like)?

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

If we were given the task of proving [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity) using a formal logic system, which logic system out there would be the most convenient for such a task? And more or less what would the proof look like, assuming that we are not allowed to "cheat" (i.e. we cannot go the "easy route" of assuming Euler's identity as axiom because ... that's just boring).

Comment: As touched on in my (potentially non-answer) answer, this question depends on what exactly you view the "Euler identity" as being. To even ask the question precisely, you already need a formal framework and series of definitions. Of course, in any framework there will be a large variety of possible proofs. There is no "the" proof. Still, informally "equivalent" versions can be considered in a variety of frameworks. However, which will be "most convenient" is not an objective fact and falls under being a matter of opinion as well as highly contextual.

Comment: The actual logical statement of the theorem isn't the equality, it is that the equality is consistent and that the usual rules of exponents still apply.

Answer (score 1):

The main hurdle to a complete formalization of this in the "usual" way would be formalizing the real numbers and the parts of real analysis that you would need and proving all the basic properties.

One approach to avoid this would be to use formal power series. These can be formalized as infinite sequences of, in this case, complex rationals, say. That is, simply functions $\mathbb N \to \mathbb Q[i]$. The function $a : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q[i]$ would correspond to the formal power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)x^n/n!$. The nice thing about this representation is that differentation is simply $Da(n) = a(n+1)$. You can then define the exponential function and $\sin$ and $\cos$ via "differential equations": $D\exp=\exp$ and $\exp(0)=1$ and $DD\sin=-\sin$, $D\sin(0)=1$, $\sin(0)=0$, $\cos=D\sin$. You'll, of course, need to formalize some of the basic arithmetic of formal power series, but this is much more straightforward than the reals. You'll also need to prove that those "differential equations" give unique solutions, but this isn't that hard. (Alternatively, you could just directly define the sequences.)

Given this, proving $\exp\circ\,iX = \cos + i\sin$ where $X(n)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }n=1\\0,&\text{if }n\neq 1\end{cases}$ is fairly straightforward. Just some simple equational reasoning for the most part. All of this would be *relatively* easy to formalize and do in something like Coq.

Proving $e^{i\pi}=-1$ will be trickier because you can't say $\pi$ in the approach I've suggested. However, you can pick some power series that evaluates to $\pi$ when evaluated at some (complex) rational. Call that power series $p$ and let's say $p$ evaluated at $1$ would be $\pi$. You could then make the composition $\exp\circ\, ip$. Then, the only bit of anything like real analysis you would need to do is prove that the resulting power series when evaluated at $1$ converges to $-1$. That is, given any positive rational $\epsilon$, you can find a natural $N_\epsilon$ such that $|{-1}-\sum_{n=0}^{N_\epsilon}(\exp\circ\, ip)(n)/n!| < \epsilon$. This will likely require some cleverness, though $p$ and $\exp\circ\, ip$ are likely to be fairly well-behaved. For example, it's likely you can arrange it so that you are working entirely with a rational sequence rather than a complex rational sequence, and it's likely you can get decent monoticinity properties. Ultimately, it will just be finding a bound for a sequence of (complex) rationals; nothing crazy should be needed. In particular, everything described is completely computable. If you did use Coq, for example, you'd actually be able to extract a program that when run would actually give you a natural number $N_\epsilon$ given a particular rational $\epsilon$, and then you could actually perform the summation up to the produced $N_\epsilon$ to verify that it is indeed within $\epsilon$ of $-1$.

Comment: In your formalization of power series and derivatives, would you have to deal with the formalization of the concept of [limit](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Formal_Definition_of_the_Limit) and prove the existence of the limit every time you invoke a power series or derivative (either by proving the whole thing from scratch each time or maybe proving general predicates that then you can reuse to efficiently infer the existence of the limit in each case)?

Comment: No, because they're *formal* power series. The definition I gave, i.e. functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q[i]$ and $Da(n)=a(n+1)$ are the complete definitions. There are no side conditions. However, if you want to actually "sum" these series for a particular value of $x$, like I do in the last paragrah, *then* you'll run into issues where you start needing concepts from real analysis. The description I gave in the last paragraph is essentially a direct description of a Cauchy sequence. Not every formal power series will correspond to a function on the complex numbers.

Comment: You could argue that my description never proves that these formal power series actually correspond to the "usual" definitions which would be a completely correct statement. It's easy to informally verify this, but to formally verify it would require introducing the machinery of real analysis just to state most of the "usual" definitions. I tried to pick a point that abstracted away the most tedious details while not being completely trivial. Incidentially, the approach I suggest depends on very little, which shows that the identity $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ is a quite general fact.